# std::getline from std::cin - input history by up/down button not working in linux

Tags: c++, linux, bash, cin, getline

Console program receiving user input line by line using this code

```
while ( _run ) { 
    std::cout << "\n > ";
    std::string cmd = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, cmd);
    /* do something */
}
```

If user want to repeat previous line, he/she will use up/down keyboard keys to navigate to. In windows it works fine, but in Linux i see this characters instead of previous line:

```
^[[A - for up key
^[[B - for down key
^[[C - for right key
^[[D - for left key
```

Also not working navigation in current line with left/right keyboard buttons.

How to fix it?

Comment: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: This is a bash problem, not a C++ problem.

Comment: Maybe. But there are some programs (like postgresql, mysql, gdb) where it works fine...

Comment: This is *definitely* not a Bash problem!

Comment: It's working with readline. Thank you, @NeilButterworth